# How can I upload a large zip file to Amazon Glacier with .NET, using Amazon.Glacier.Transfer.ArchiveTransferManager.Upload?

Tags: c#, .net, amazon-web-services

[EDIT]: The focus of the question is how to properly use Amazon.Glacier.Transfer.ArchiveTransferManager.Upload in Amazon's .NET SDK.

I'm writing a simple application to zip a directory and upload it to Amazon's Glacier storage. I was able to upload a simple directory (12MB), but when I attempted the same feat with a larger directory (4GB), I got an error upon attempting to upload: "Invalid Content-Length: 0".

Also, when I did the test with the small directory, my program never got to the line that displays the ArchiveId and Checksum, after uploading.

Here's my code:

```
private static ArchiveTransferManager manager;
    private static string vaultName = "SuperDuperBackUp";
    private static int percentComplete;

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Zip it good.");
            var directory = @"E:\Adventures";
            var zipFile = @"E:\Adventures.zip";
            ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(directory, zipFile, CompressionLevel.Optimal, includeBaseDirectory: false);

            Console.WriteLine("To the cloud!");
            using (manager = new ArchiveTransferManager(Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1))
            {
                UploadArchive(zipFile);
            }
        }
        catch (AmazonGlacierException e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
        catch (AmazonServiceException e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }
        catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine(e.Message); }

        Console.WriteLine("Done.");
        Console.Read();
    }

    private static void UploadArchive(string archiveToUpload)
    {
        percentComplete = 0;
        var uploadOptions = new UploadOptions();
        uploadOptions.StreamTransferProgress += new EventHandler<StreamTransferProgressArgs>(onStreamTransferProgress);
        var archive = manager.Upload(vaultName, "archive description", archiveToUpload, uploadOptions);

        //never gets here
        Console.WriteLine("ArchiveId: {0}, CheckSum: {1}", archive.ArchiveId, archive.Checksum);
    }

    private static void onStreamTransferProgress(object sender, StreamTransferProgressArgs args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Progress: {0} / {1} ({2}%)", args.TransferredBytes, args.TotalBytes, args.PercentDone);
        percentComplete = args.PercentDone;
    }
```

Comment: I think 4GB may be a limitation for uploading. Have a look at this discussion around uploading large files to IIS that includes a discussion about large files. I bet the same concept applies to AWS http://forums.asp.net/post/5011951.aspx

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/uploading-an-archive.html confirms the 4GB limit, although multipart is recommended for anything over 100MB... but if the code isn't behaving as expected on the small file, you need to understand why, first...

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot the Amazon.Glacier.Transfer.ArchiveTransferManager.Upload function's intellisense summary comment indicates that "For larger archives, this method uses Glacier's multipart upload API to split the upload into multiple parts", so it sounds like they abstract that work away. 

And, on a related note, I was able to upload the file to an S3 bucket using their Amazon.S3.Transfer.TransferUtility.Upload, which uses "Amazon S3's multipart API".

Comment: As for the misbehavior on the small file, I'll keep pluggin' away at it and let you know if I find anything. But, for now, I guess it's part of my question...

@JamieClayton I'm using a console app, but I threw in that webserver config just for good measure with the maxAllowedContentLength setting turned waay up and got the same error.

Comment: @JohnnyFun my mistake.  I prefer to work closer to the wire, as it were, so the majority of my code speaks directly to the REST endpoints... so I'm not familiar with the SDK and I missed that point when I looked at the docs.

Comment: Side point. += new EventHandler<T> doesn't have a -= new EventHandler<T> to disconnect the event on completion. I found this caused issues when testing multiple times.

Comment: @JamieClayton I ran into some oddities with that event handler, too. I updated "onStreamTransferProgress" to only display the percentage when it changed, by simply wrapping it's body with if (args.PercentDone > percentComplete), and when it got to 100%, amazon came back with an error saying that my request signature is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

You can use amazon glacier multipart upload Low-Level API instead of using `ArchiveTransferManager`(High-Level API) and to implement this here is the documentation.

Documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/uploading-archive-mpu.html

I uploaded archive with size larger than 20 GB using [multipart upload Low-Level API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonglacier/latest/dev/uploading-an-archive-mpu-using-dotnet.html#uploading-an-archive-in-parts-highlevel-using-dotnet) without any problem.

Comment: Michael-sqlbot mentioned the same thing, but the .NET SDK method I'm using indicates that it does a multipart upload behind the scenes.

Comment: I am sorry I wasn't notice that Michael-sqlbot mentioned the same thing in the comments but I was meant that you can use multipart upload functions from the same SDK instead of using ArchiveTransferManager

Comment: No worries, man. I'll edit my question and make it more specific to how to properly use "Amazon.Glacier.Transfer.ArchiveTransferManager.Upload".

Comment: I'll try using the low-level API instead, after work today, though, and let you know how that goes.